# Calculating delta values using kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have some metrics written to Kafka topic with a timestamp. I need to calculate the delta value between the current value and the previous value of the metric. I would like to do this via the Kafka streams API or KSQL to scale better than the current solution that I have.

What I have now is a simple Kafka producer/consumer in Python that reads a metric at time and calculates the the delta with the previous value stored in a Redis database.

Some example code to accomplish this via Kafka streams API would be highly appreciated.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Check out the docs and examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I have gone through those examples but I couldn't find one that addresses my use case. Can you tell me which API I should look at?

Comment: @zzz10n have a look at `KStream#groupBy` and `KGroupedStream#aggregate`.